# Titanium Studio App fireEvent not working?

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile

I am working with Titanium Studio to develop android application. I want to launch one window, while the user login time. when the user gets successful login, it should display before showing the main screen.

my code in login screen as : `Ti.App.fireEvent('TestCall');`

code in

```
Titanium.App.addEventListener('TestCall', function(e) {
    load();
});
```

will any one suggest me how to resolve this?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Try `Ti.App.fireEvent('TestCall');`. Unless you provide more info or code it will be hard to debug. Also, the bug may exist in load. Have you set a breakpoint inside the listener?

Comment: Yes @josiah, but it is not firing

Answer (score 0):

First i would like to explain my understanding about your question.

You are trying to perform some operation after successfully login and after completion of that you want to show next screen.

So according to that, looks like you are trying to fireEvent which is not yet added because your window where you added that listener is not yet loaded/ opened.

Thanks